# DateTimeSerializer: what is parameter shapeOverride for?

Tags: serialization, jackson, jodatime, fasterxml

com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.ser.DateTimeSerializer#DateTimeSerializer(JacksonJodaDateFormat format, int shapeOverride)

I can't figure out the meaning of shapeOverride. Could not find proper information on the internet about it. So what does it mean, what is it for?

Comment: I am also interested in finding out the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hint to Jackson to tell it what the fields "shape" is. Shape is basically data type. I don't know if you have ever serialized a Joda object and got an array before, but this is basically shape.

Is it an Array, String, or Timestamp?

The override is any non-0 value. So if you provide 0 you will get the default, and the default is ARRAY.

So pass the following based on how you want to serialize your data:

- No Override = 0
- STRING = 1
- TIMESTAMP = 2
- ARRAY = 3

You can see their explination in  com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.ser.JodaDateSerializerBase

```
    public abstract class JodaDateSerializerBase<T> extends JodaSerializerBase<T>
    // need contextualization to read per-property annotations
        implements ContextualSerializer
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        // // Since 2.9

        protected final static int FORMAT_STRING = 1;
        protected final static int FORMAT_TIMESTAMP = 2;
        protected final static int FORMAT_ARRAY = 3;

        protected final JacksonJodaDateFormat _format;

        protected final SerializationFeature _featureForNumeric;

        /**
        * Shape to use for generic "use numeric" feature (instead of more specific
        * JsonFormat.shape).
        *
        * @since 2.9
        */
        protected final int _defaultNumericShape;

        /**
        * Marker set to non-0 if (and only if) property or type override exists.
        *
        * @since 2.9
        */
        protected final int _shapeOverride;
```